# Planets game, unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello hello back again!

So i'm trying to create like a planet game and I've got it pretty nice so far, it supports 1 planet. And when I add another planet the second on repels the player away from it.

```
void Start()
    {
        Planets = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Planet");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        foreach (GameObject planet in Planets)
        {
            if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, planet.transform.position) <= maxDist)
            {
                maxDist = planet.GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().radius + planet.transform.localScale.x;
                Vector3 desiredPosition = planet.transform.position;
                smoothedPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, desiredPosition, speed);// smoothSpeed);
                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(smoothedPosition * -1);
                smoothedPosition = Vector3.zero;
            }
        }
    }
```

The code gets all the planets and puts them in an array of GameObjects, then i loop through them and check the distance between them if it is bigger than `CircleCollider.radius + planet.transform.localScale.x` then it makes the player move towards it, but like i stated earlier it repels it on the second planet for some reason instead of moving it towards the planet

What could be wrong in this part?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should you calculate `maxDist` before comparing?

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, but i changed something so now it doesn't repel but it doesn't get attracted to it

Comment: And I don't understand why did you use `MoveTowards`. If you want to push the player to the planet, the correct (force) direction is `desiredPosition - transform.position`.

Comment: Fixed! Thank you! this worked for me 
```Vector3 desiredPosition = planet.transform.position/* + GameManager.instance.Cameraoffset*/;
                    smoothedPosition = (desiredPosition - transform.position) * -1/*Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, desiredPosition, speed)*/;
                    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(smoothedPosition * -1);
                    smoothedPosition = Vector3.zero;```
That is inbetween the if statement :)

Comment: Consider posting that as an answer with credit going to **shingo**.  Also avoid calling `GetComponent` during gameplay.  Stick it in a variable

Comment: I have posted an answer, I said thank you to shingo in it as well. I was using ```GetComponent``` first then change it when I get it working. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void Start()
    {
        Planets = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Planet");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        foreach (GameObject planet in Planets)
        {                
            maxDist = planet.GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().radius + planet.transform.localScale.x;

            if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, planet.transform.position) <= maxDist)
            {
                    Vector3 desiredPosition = planet.transform.position/* + GameManager.instance.Cameraoffset*/;
                    smoothedPosition = (desiredPosition - transform.position) * -1/*Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, desiredPosition, speed)*/;
                    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(smoothedPosition * -1);
                    smoothedPosition = Vector3.zero;
            }
        }
    }
```

This code worked after changing it, thankyou shingo :)